# Dynamic creation of element and class implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, createelement, sparklines

I have problem with dynamic creation of element in javascript with innerHTML. Here is the code:

```
var newElement  = document.createElement("tr");
newElement.innerHTML = ['<td><a href="javascript:void(0);">Test Suite</a></td><td>4,977</td><td class="text-align-center">',
                      '<div class="sparkline txt-color-blue text-align-center" data-sparkline-height="22px" data-sparkline-width="90px" data-sparkline-barwidth="2">2700, 3631, 2471, 1300, 1877, 2500, 2577, 2700, 3631, 2471, 2000, 2100, 3000</div>',
            ].join('\n');

$("#locationsGraph").append(newElement);
```

The problem is that the Element is created just right, but the element class is not implemented.

With this part:

```
class="sparkline txt-color-blue text-align-center" data-sparkline-height="22px" data-sparkline-width="90px" data-sparkline-barwidth="2"
```

I should get a bar graph, but instead I get the same list of numbers.

Is it something with the implementation of the class in innerHTML or what?
I also tried manually creating all elements and assigning className but the result was the same

Comment: Presumably what ever you are using to create the chart isn't running on the newly created element. You probably need to call it again to have it transform the DOM into an actual chart.

Comment: How exactly are those numbers form a 'bar graph'? You probably need to call some method to do this...

Comment: This is just a demo for inline barGraph, these numbers are random numbers for the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs), you need to run `$(newElement).find('div').sparkline()`.

Comment: hooray success :)) Thanks man, i am new to javascript/jquery and it didn't occurred to me to check the documentation for sparkline.

Comment: @autodev101: In the future you'll find you'll get better results if you include information such as which tools you are using (i.e sparkline) *in the question*.

Comment: @MattBurland to be honest i didn't even know that sparkline is a tool, i am working on a template and i have a deadline so things had to be done quickly, but in the future i will. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a closing  to match your

```
newElement.innerHTML = ['<td><a href="javascript:void(0);">Test Suite</a></td><td>4,977</td><td class="text-align-center">',
                      '<div class="sparkline txt-color-blue text-align-center" data-sparkline-height="22px" data-sparkline-width="90px" data-sparkline-barwidth="2">2700, 3631, 2471, 1300, 1877, 2500, 2577, 2700, 3631, 2471, 2000, 2100, 3000</div>',
          '</td>' //this is missing
  ].join('\n');
```